# Add Arrays from database in a json encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wanted to add all arrays from my database in one json encode and decode it later on.. but I ran into a thing which I don't know how to fix.

I'm trying to add all arrays from the sql query in one array and then encode that one array with all the arrays inside it.

My current code:

```
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server.';dbname='.$this->database.'', $this->user, $this->pass);
        $result = array();
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from bier') as $row) {
           $result[] += $row;
        }
        print json_encode($result);
```

Updated code:

```
function getData()
    {
    try {

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server.';dbname='.$this->database.'', $this->user, $this->pass);
        $result = array();
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from bier') as $row) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        $json = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        var_dump($json);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
```

Currently returns: **Boolean False**

Comment: Remove `+` from this statement `$result[] += $row;`.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I tried that but then it doesn't show anything if I try to print it

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul No errors are shown

Comment: @RyanVincent It worked when i just var_dumped the $result :) thanks!

Comment: Taking a best guess duplicate to close here. Double check your *data encoding.* If that's not it, update your question with new information about that area and we can reopen it.

Comment: @BananaCoder :: look at the answer, you need: `$data->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` ... as pointed out by @RyanVincent

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the `+=` compound operator is used to "add & assign"; however, this does not work as you'd expect for inserting items into an array.

Your code should work if you remove the `+` from that line as @Rajdeep pointed out.

Here is your code, updated with some changes for clarity:

```
try
{
    $data = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server.';dbname='.$this->database.'', $this->user, $this->pass);
    $data->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $list = [];

    foreach($data->query('SELECT * from bier') as $item)
    { $list[] = $item; }

    $json = json_encode($list, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    echo $json;
}
catch (PDOException $fail)
{
    echo $fail->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

As you probably notice; the `[] =` character sequence after a variable name (that is an array) inserts the new item in the array being assigned.

The `try --> catch` block should indicate if there was a problem.

Here's more info on how to check for errors: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Thanks alot! but it still seems that if i try to echo or print it nothing will be shown :/

Comment: Make sure that the data-base connection settings are correct, and make sure there is data in the data-base table `bier` as suggested by your `select` query.

Comment: That's all fine i've testted it

Comment: @BananaCoder :: I've updated the answer and added a link that explains PDO connections, and also shows how to detect errors, as this may be what's causing your results to be empty.

Comment: @BananaCoder :: I've added the code to force throwing errors if any, so, the try / catch should handle that if errors are thrown, and display what went wrong. Don't forget to test the code, this latest code update here will most likely work - or at least show you what went wrong.

Comment: I've updated the topic so you can see my current code, Now if i try to echo it or var dump it it will return Boolean false I've no clue why it's saying that :/

Comment: @BananaCoder :: there must be something obvious you're missing; look through your code; have a look here on how exactly it works: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php  .. if you're still having issues, then, try using **mysqli** instead of _PDO_

Comment: @BananaCoder :: In your updated code, I see you did not add the `$data->setAttribute(...)` code; so, it will not show any errors, that's why you're getting `false`.. Have a look at my updated answer, copy+paste & test, it should work.